# How to approximate the size of a text file containing a matrix, written by Fortran?

Tags: file, matrix, fortran

I have written an `N*N` matrix to a formatted text file using Fortran. The [Fortran output format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007437a2e/index.html) was `N(3X,E17.8)`, where `N` is the matrix size.

Example of one matrix element:    `0.19860753E-08` i.e. "(three spaces)0.19860753E-08".

A `558x558` Matrix has a file size of `5.294.302 Bytes`.

How could I approximate the file size for an `N*N` matrix for any value of `N`?

Comment: What has Python to do with the question?

Comment: I assume that the matrix was created with Fortran and is being read by Python. But it is very unclear. Please see [ask] and tell us and show us something more.

Comment: You really need to tell us more. The question in this shape is unanswerable. Please do see [ask].

Comment: What programming language are you using for the import? How does the file.look like?

Comment: Are all tags need to be the name of programming languages? I don't need to import this txt anymore.

Comment: I have simply no idea what and where you are trying to do and what tools you are using. Forget tags. Explain what you are doing.

Comment: I want to know in advance what will be the size of the exported file if I know the size of the matrix

Comment: You really have to write your questions more clearly. You should have shown the exact code that prints the matrix. It is also good to use standard terms. You Python tag was a big mistake because many people who can closose your question are active in that tag.

Comment: An `N*N` matrix will have a file size `a*N^2+b*N+c`, with constants `a`, `b` and `c`. You could probably calculate the constants from the details of the file format, but it's probably easier to just fit them by making files for a few different matrix sizes `N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have the lines separate or just all numbers in sequence.

If I read your description correctly you have `N(3X,E17.8)` *per line*. In that case every character is one byte. 3 spaces + 17 characters = 20 bytes. One line is 20 * N + 1 (or + 2 on Windows).  The +1 or +2 is the line end marker (LF or CR + LF). (This distinction is what the `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` utilities convert.)

Then you have N lines, so it should be N*(20 * N + 1).

That does not correspond to the numbers you show.

But the example you show is not consistent with the format you show. The number    `0.19860753E-08` is actually just 17 characters `(3X,E14.8)`. In that case it is `N*(17 * N +1 ) + 1` or eventually `N*(17 * N + 2)` with CR + LF. Which corresponds to the file size you quoted much better. 558 * (17 * 558 + 2) = 5 294 304.

Comment: The second approach is more reasonable. In the original (not edited) question was `N(E17.8)`, where 17 is a number of all characters of one element, 8 is a number of decimal digits. Many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

For a single record written by a format like

```
write (*, '(999(3X,E17.8)') a
```

we can determine how many characters would be written.  For each element there will be three spaces followed by a field of width 17: a total of 20 characters for each element. There will then be a number of characters to end the record (depending on filesystem, operating system, etc., usually one or two).

Knowing how large each record is, and how many records are written, you have the size. Depending again on system settings, you may also see a separate end-of-file marker of some size.

We can answer this question because we know how large each field is going to be. We don't always know that from a format. For example, with some edit descriptors the field width is determined later on: `A`, `I0`, `G0.6`, etc., are such.

Finally, note also that without colon editing we may get extra output for an element. `X` is a special case, if we instead had

```
write (*, '(999("   ",E17.8)') a
```

then there would be three spaces additional spaces after the final element written out before the end of the record. This can be prevented in

```
write (*, '(999("   ":,,E17.8)') a
```

`X` is a position edit descriptor: it doesn't actually transfer data so doesn't add to the transfer count unless further data are written.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calculating the size of the file from the details of the code and the file format, it may be simpler to write out files containing matrices with (at least) three different values of `N`. You can then fit the file size `S` as a function of `N`, as

```
S = a*N^2 + b*N + c
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are constants which you will get from the fit.

- The `a*N^2` term comes from the representation of the numbers in the matrix.
- The `b*N` term comes from line endings, and any value separators you might be using.
- The `c` term comes from file metadata, and any spare characters you might have in your file.